# Understanding $PATH variable: Installed gems are not in path

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems

Good Morning!

I am working on ruby gem. So far, the gem has not been pushed to any server - all local development for now.

I would like to test out the gem as I build it (using TTD).  I have run `bundle exe rake build` and `bundle exe rake install` to build and install the gem in my local environment.  I now expect that when I type `gem_name` anywhere in my terminal that `gem_name` should be recognized. Unfortunately it isn't; instead I get this error:

```
    `$ -bash gem_name: command not found`
```

The only thing I can possible thing of that might be leading to this is some problem with my path.

Here is the output of my $PATH:

```
    echo $PATH
    /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:
    /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:
    /Users/throw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:
    /usr/local:/usr/local/bin:
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
   /usr/local/git/bin:/Users/throw/.rvm/bin:/Users/throw/.nvm/nvm.sh:
  /Users/throw/.node/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/9.5.0.0/latest/bin
```

And here is the output of the command `gem env`:

```
    gem env
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
      - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [x86_64-darwin14]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
      - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/throw/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/throw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
      - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/throw/.gem/specs
      - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/throw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/etc
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-darwin-14
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
         - /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
      - GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - REMOTE SOURCES:
         - https://rubygems.org/
      - SHELL PATH:
         - /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
         - /Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin
         - /Users/throw/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
         - /usr/local
         - /usr/local/bin
         - /usr/local/sbin
         - /usr/bin
         - /usr/local/bin
         - /usr/bin
         - /bin
         - /usr/sbin
         - /sbin
         - /usr/local/git/bin
         - /Users/throw/.rvm/bin
         - /Users/throw/.nvm/nvm.sh
         - /Users/throw/.node/bin
         - /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/9.5.0.0/latest/bin
```

Thus far, I think that `gem_name` path is included in my `$PATH` but I don't know ... am I missing something?

Below is the contents of `gem_name.gemspec`:

```
    # coding: utf-8
    lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
    require 'instructortools/version'

    Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
      spec.name          = "instructortools"
      spec.version       = Instructortools::VERSION
      spec.authors       = ["Throw"]
      spec.email         = ["throw@gmail.com"]

      spec.summary       = %q{The command line interface instructor tools}
      spec.homepage      = "https://github.com/throw/instructortools-gem"
      spec.license       = "MIT"

      # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org by setting 'allowed_push_host', or
      # delete this section to allow pushing this gem to any host.
      if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
        spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
      else
        raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
      end

      spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
      spec.bindir        = "exe"
      spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
      spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

      spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.11"
      spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
      spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.0"
      spec.add_development_dependency "pry"

      spec.add_runtime_dependency "thor"
    end
```

I have an exe directory that has the following line:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

    require "instructortools"

    Instructortools::CLI.start(ARGV)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that gem contains some executable script that should be installed in path?

Comment: yes @Vasfed.  I have edited my question to address your question

Comment: What `git ls-files | grep -E '^exe'` shows?

Comment: @Vasfed: I get no output when I run that command. Is that command something that should be in my ~/.bash_profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention your executable in gemspec like so:

```
spec.bindir "exe"
spec.executables ["your_script_name"]
```

So that upon install rubygems copies it into `/Users/throw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin` which is on `$PATH`

EDIT:
Your gemspec gets file list from `git ls-files`, so all files should be commited before gem build to be included in gem.

Comment: hi @Vasfed! Edited my question to include the contents of my `gemspec` (and it includes both `spec.bindir "exe"` and `spec.executables`.  




Thank you for your help! Appreciate it :)

Comment: @userthrow it seems like you did not commit your executable yet, so it is not in `git ls-files`, so commit and then build the gem, it may be missing some more files